# Artificial gravity / physics in android development - where to start?

Tags: java, android

I did a few searches for this particular topic but came up relatively empty...  I would call myself intermediate in Java and beginner in android, so I'm not sure if I'm attempting to bite off more than I can chew at this point, but I figure the best way to learn is to (as always) chuck myself into the wolf den.

I want to get into developing android games.  I've already developed a couple apps - one will be going on the market for .99 soon, I'm kinda proud that I have something worth selling!

I don't really have a plan yet, as always, but I want to start out by familiarizing myself with physics.  Games like Angry Birds and Hill Climb Racing that seem to have really good artificial gravity and physics.  How is that done?  Where do I start to learn this stuff?  Are there any good tutorials out there?

By the way, I'm new to this site...  So if this is a question that has already been asked, I apologize - I wasn't able to locate it in a search.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you taken any school/university courses on mechanical/simple physics without regard to computing before?

Comment: I have an Associate's degree in Computer Programming which included discreet mathematics and algebra, but nothing in actual physics.

Comment: If you're serious about developing games and getting them on the market, don't waste time reinventing wheels--find a framework/library that suits your needs. Check out [libGDX](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/) (which has a [Box2D wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/PhysicsBox2D))

Comment: +1 for libdx, just take a note at its explosive taggrowth here at SO, it has a great community and great momentum in developement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angry Birds uses an open source physics engine called Box2D.

From the [website](http://www.box2d.org/features.html):

> Box2D is a feature rich 2D rigid body physics engine, written in C++ by Erin Catto. It has been used in many games, including Crayon Physics Deluxe, winner of the 2008 Independant Game Festival Grand Prize.
>
> Box2D uses the zlib license and can be used free of charge. The zlib license does not require attribution, however you should give credit to Box2D when possible.

If you're looking to start working with gravity and physics in your android games, Box2D is a great place to start.